# Use pytest fixture inside mock class

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest, python-unittest

I need to use a fixture that prepares some data inside a class that will be used to mock a third party library. Right now I have the equivalent to this:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def file(tmpdir_factory):
    """Long process that creates a mock file."""
    ...
    return file_path
```

I need to use this fixture inside the class constructor, something like:

```py
class Mock:

    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._file
```

I need the `file` fixture to be outside the `Mock` class since it is used in other places. The `Mock` class will be used very similar to this:

```py
def my_test():
    with patch("thirdparty.Class", new=Mock):
        ...
```

I tried using the `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("file")` decorator but it did not work. How can I inject the fixture to the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you patched `thirdparty.Class` with the new class `Mock`, then that means all calls to instantiate `thirdparty.Class`in the source code would use `Mock` instead.

#### Solution 1

To be able to inject the fixture `file` to be used inside the class `Mock`, you have to define it somewhere that the `Mock` class can access. You can't control it from the `__init__` because that will be called from the source code. What you can do is put that class `Mock` inside a function or fixture and then access the `file` as a variable within the function/fixture itself.

**thirdparty.py**

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self._file = file

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._file


def func():
    obj = MyClass("/path/to/real")
    file = obj.get()
    print("File to process:", file)
    return file
```

**test_thirdparty.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import pytest

from thirdparty import func


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def file():
    return "/path/to/mock"


@pytest.fixture
def my_mock_class(file):  # This can also be an ordinary function (not a fixture). You just need to pass the <file>.
    class MyMockClass:
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self._file = file  # Ignore the entered file in the initialization (__init__). Instead, read the injected file from the current fixture itself (my_mock_class).

        def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self._file

    return MyMockClass


def test_real_file():
    assert func() == "/path/to/real"


def test_mock_file(my_mock_class):
    with patch("thirdparty.MyClass", new=my_mock_class):
        assert func() == "/path/to/mock"
```

**Output**

```
$ pytest -q -rP
..                                                             [100%]
=============================== PASSES ===============================
___________________________ test_real_file ___________________________
------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------
File to process: /path/to/real
___________________________ test_mock_file ___________________________
------------------------ Captured stdout call ------------------------
File to process: /path/to/mock
2 passed in 0.05s
```

#### Solution 2

In the source code, find those that instantiates it:

```
the_class = thirdparty.Class(some_file)
```

Then, trace where `some_file` was created. Let's say this is from a function call:

```
some_file = get_file()
```

You then need to patch how `get_file()` to return the value of of the fixture `file` so that when `thirdparty.Class` is created (or rather `Mock` since we already patched it), the value for `self._file` would be the one in the fixture.

```
mocker.patch('get_file", return_value=file)  # Where <file> is the fixture
```